# Firebase authentication in Chrome Extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get authentication (email/password) to work in a Chrome Extension. I seems to work just fine if I put my authentication code in the background script. However I can't seem to get it to work as a browser action script.

I used the following code as the base of my extension: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-chrome-extension

I changed browser_action.js to:

```
Firebase.enableLogging(true);
var f = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/');

f.authWithPassword({    
    email    : "a@b.cd",
    password : "1234"
}, function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
        alert("Login Failed!", error);
} else {
    alert("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
}
});
```

And I kept the existing browser_action.html unchanged:

```
<!doctype html>


<style type="text/css">
    #mainPopup {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
</style>

<div id="mainPopup">
<h1>Firebase test!</h1>
<p>Clicks: <span id="contents"></span></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="browser_action.js"></script>
```

When I load the extension and click on the icon it gives the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: f.authWithPassword is not a function
```

If I move the firebase code and authentication code to background.js file it works and gives me an alert that it is succesfully authenticated.

What am I doing wrong or why is this not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That example chrome extension hasn't been updated in 3 years, so its version of Firebase is out-of-date.  Replace `https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js` with `https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js` in `browser_action.html` and you should be able to use `authWithPassword` successfully.

Comment: I'm an idiot :') ... I assumed v0 meant it would always get the latest version of the library. I was wrong XD

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming across this since July 2016, Firebase has an updated set of instructions on how to setup auth for Chrome Extensions (in their example they use Google Auth). I jumped through a bunch of hoops before coming across this post..hopefully save someone time. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension

Comment: Trouble is, that code example is also out of date: in the README, the author references a UI element in the Firebase console that no longer exists: Whitelist client IDs from external projects (optional).